# popToViewControllerAnimated does not animate since ios5

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios5

as topic describes, calling `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` / `popToViewControllerAnimated` does not do any animation anymore.

the code I use, which works fine with 4.x, is simply

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

so nothing special here. I just noticed, that for all my apps, running on iOS5, pop-animations have been gone. push-animations however DO appear.

now i wonder what to search for, if there is the need to define the transition/style of that animation?

Any help welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, calling "[super viewWillAppear]" in  "viewWillDisappear" is sort of ... my bad!

Comment: I am facing same problem... will you please elaborate your answer ?

Comment: yes.
i had a custom tabbar controller, based on the UITabbarController Apple provides. in viewWillDisappear i called [super viewWILLappear]; so changing this do its proper method helped out.   do you also have a custom tabbar or something?

Comment: yes same thing.. custom tabbar by sub classing UITabbarController

Comment: so I have to write [super viewWILLappear];  in viewWillDisappear ?

Comment: nono calling will_APPEAR_ in _DISAPPEAR_ was the actual bug!
give me more information about how you pop your view controller

Comment: by [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: with "more" i was thinking of "more" :)

Comment: I have 4 tabs. Each having more then one VC inside. When I push VC it makes animation properly but not when I pop VC !!!

Answer (score 2):

Was having the same problem. view transition animation for poptoRootViewControllerAnimated was working fine pre ios5.0 but not in ios5. Below is a brief description to fix it.

I had implemented a custom Tab bar in view A. When I transitioned to view B from A and then back, the view transition animation stopped working for B to A. Upon looking at the view loading methods in view A and all its sub-views, my customTabBar in view A had ViewDidAppear that was erroneously calling [super viewWillAppear] inside it. When I corrected it to [super viewDidAppear] , the pop animation started happening OK.

Looks like pre iOS 5, it did not matter but now it does and rightfully so.