# viewWillDisappear not called when calling popToRootViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I work on a legacy application, and have found out, that my `view[Will/Did]Disappear` methods are not always fired properly.

The case is, I have a (custom) `UIViewController` set as rootViewController in AppDelegate. This rootViewController has a `UINavigationController`, which has two view controllers pushed on it. When the user presses the home button, the user is logged out. When he later returns to the app, the application calls `[UINavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` and then displays a modal `UIViewController` for logging in.

The problem is: When I push/pop on the `UINavigationController` normally, my `viewWillDisappear` method is called properly. But when I use the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method, `viewWillDisappear` is not called on any of the viewControllers that are popped off.

Searching on the internet has only given two possible reasons:

- [If using a UINavigationController as a subview, you must call `view[Will/Did]Disappear` yourself](http://davidebenini.it/2009/01/03/viewwillappear-not-being-called-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/)
- [Not calling the proper super methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846932/poptoviewcontrolleranimated-does-not-animate-since-ios5)

None of these suggestions are the case in my app. And I have no idea where to look. Anybody has a suggestion to what has been done wrong in the app?

Comment: good find :). Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The view probably wasn't onscreen. It has to be onscreen (visible) for the `viewWillDisappear:` method to be called. If it's coming back from the background, it wasn't visible.

You could try using `willMoveToParentViewController:` which is called when the view controller is removed from its parent.

Comment: That is a very interesting suggestion! I have now tried using popToRootViewController on another place in the app, and then my viewWillDisappear are called as expected, so you are right so far. However, I also tried making a test app, with exactly my setup, where `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` is called from AppDelegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive:`. Here, the `viewWillDisappear:` method is also called. This still suggests, that it ought to be called, but something is wrong in my app.

Comment: The reason for this to happen turned out to be, that I was presenting a modal view controller when the `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method was called (just after calling `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`). So your answer was correct - the view apparently was off the screen when the app launched.

Comment: After bringing this issue up with Apple' technical support, it turned out to be a bug in iOS (and it appears in both 6 and 7 Beta 5). I have filed a bug report to Apple. I give you +1 for the good suggestion using `willMoveToParentViewController` as a workaround :-)

Comment: @JRV Good to know, thanks for going to the trouble. You might want to post it on Open Radar (http://openradar.appspot.com/) too so people know about it.

Comment: Interesting page - thanks for pointing it out. I have now posted the bug: http://openradar.appspot.com/14744330

Comment: :) Thanks for posting this workaround. I was facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

such useful to me

```
[nav performSelector:@selector(popToRootViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
```

I rewrote UITabBarController

```
- (void)setSelectedIndex:(NSUInteger)selectedIndex {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [originalViewController as:[UINavigationController class]];
        if (navigationController.presentedViewController) {
            [navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            }];
        }else if (navigationController.topViewController){
            [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    });
```

}