# In iOS 13.x SDK viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear doesn't called during popToRootViewController action

Tags: swift, ios13

When I stared to use new iOS 13 SDK, I noticed, that when I want to back to main window in navigation stack using popToRootNavigationController system not trigger currently methods like viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear. I know, that in new iOS there is some changes in modal presentation style, but in my case I use typical view presenting(push etc.). In previous versions of SDK I didn't notice any problem with that. Did someone have similar problem to mine?

Comment: Check it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954402/viewwilldisappear-not-called-when-calling-poptorootviewcontrolleranimated